# Issue with destinationVC and member types

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uistoryboardsegue

Would someone mind helping me finish this little project of mine? For those of you who keep tabs on questions I've asked here, I've had problems adjusting to the code necessary for nested arrays and my project lies exactly in that.

Just in case my code looks odd/unfamiliar, my project is based off this tutorial by Jared Davidson, here is the youtube link for the project.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pR6dR-vVZeY

and here is my project (it's on Dropbox),

> https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u9rkvwsrcdoa7q8/AABwKm_djSB2oENzuJNT1u35a?dl=0

I'm really just having problems with my prepareforsegue functions and this piece of code.

```
 var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
 var DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! RestaurantNameTable

 var selectedRestaurants : [Restaurant]

 selectedRestaurants = restaurantNamesArray[indexPath.section]

 DestViewController.restaurantNamesArray = selectedRestaurants
```

basically, my restaurantNamesTable does not have a member named restaurantNamesArray.
or should my code goes as follows...

```
DestViewController.selectedRestaurants =restaurantNamesArray[indexPath.section]
```

?

im a little lost right at the very end.  any help would truly be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: what's the error you get ?

Comment: picture of error has been uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RestaurantNameTable` has a property called `selectedRestaurants` but not one called `restaurantNamesArray`, so you are getting an error attempting to write to it.

You want

```
var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
var DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! RestaurantNameTable
var selectedRestaurants : [Restaurant]
selectedRestaurants = restaurantNamesArray[indexPath.section]

DestViewController.selectedRestaurants = selectedRestaurants
```

or more safely and succinctly

```
if let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? RestaurantNameTable {
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    destViewController.selectedRestaurants = restaurantNamesArray[indexPath.section]
}
```

Comment: thank you, kindly!  one last issue, would you happen to understand why my second control just displays two cells with the generic "label" text instead of the restaurant name?  here is the updated project/dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u9rkvwsrcdoa7q8/AABwKm_djSB2oENzuJNT1u35a?dl=0

Comment: I can't look at that right now, but a common reason would be not setting the tableview datasource or delegate properties or not setting the custom class for the viewcontroller in the storyboard scene

Comment: I was able to solve that problem by creating a second table cell.  However, I've noticed, that my mcdonalds and burger king instances are pushed to every second table cell despite only being wanted in the first one.